# Grails 4 application.groovy: Is variable declaration allowed? Causes a bug reported from micronaut

Tags: grails, micronaut, grails-4

We are Migrating from Grails 2 to Grails 4. Extremely simplified, our application.groovy is like this:

```
def someVar = [:]

environments {

  myGreatApp.brandMap = [
    'dev.analyzor1.com': someVar
  ]
}
```

This causes an error, complaining about the variable 'someVar' not created.

```
ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Exception occurred reading configuration [application]: BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'Script1.groovy' tried to get a variable with the name someVar as stack variable, but a variable with this name was not created
    at io.micronaut.context.env.groovy.GroovyPropertySourceLoader.processInput(GroovyPropertySourceLoader.java:53)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.AbstractPropertySourceLoader.read(AbstractPropertySourceLoader.java:112)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.AbstractPropertySourceLoader.loadProperties(AbstractPropertySourceLoader.java:97)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.AbstractPropertySourceLoader.load(AbstractPropertySourceLoader.java:73)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.AbstractPropertySourceLoader.load(AbstractPropertySourceLoader.java:59)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourceLoader.load(PropertySourceLoader.java:51)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.loadPropertySourceFromLoader(DefaultEnvironment.java:608)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.readPropertySourceList(DefaultEnvironment.java:541)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment.readPropertySourceList(DefaultApplicationContext.java:675)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.readPropertySources(DefaultEnvironment.java:463)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.start(DefaultEnvironment.java:324)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:647)
```

I am migrating a large application and stuff like this is all over, after moving code from Config.groovy and DataSource.groovy to application.groovy.

> Is there a workaround for not being able to declare and use a variable in application.groovy? Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but does the same thing happen if you put your variables in runtime.groovy?

Comment: There was some fixes in 4.0.3 related to processing application.groovy - are you on the latest?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out, just removing the "def" makes the error go away, like this:

```
someVar = [:] // was: def someVar = [:]

environments {

  myGreatApp.brandMap = [
    'dev.analyzor1.com': someVar
  ]
}
```

I cannot claim it works fully at runtime as the converted application is still far away from running, but at least syntactically this works.